# Converting multiple Option[T] to a List[T]

Tags: scala

I have several Option[T] that I would like to convert to a List[T]. I'm attempting to achieve this with a for comprehension:

```
val someOption: Option[(String, String)] = Some(("bla", "woo"))
val anotherOption: Option[String] = None

val result = for {
  (a, b) <- someOption
  c <- anotherOption
} yield List(a, b, c)
```

However `result` in this case becomes of type `Option[List[String]]` and contains `None`. How can I instead have `result` become of type `List[String]` with a value of `List("bla", "woo")`.

Edit: This is a contrived example, in reality I need to use `a` and `b` to instantiate `SomeOtherThing(a, b)` and have that be a list item.

Comment: Well... the most intricate piece of this puzzle is to provide an implicit conversion from your `T` to deconstructed components `a, b`. And even then... what about the loss of `types` of your components when you put them into a generic `List`. You can probably keep the types by making it so that your implicit deconstructor also `tags` the components with corresponding types, but then... how do you put them into that generic list ?

Comment: And looking at your edit, you do not want a generic solution and are just looking for solving it to this particular case.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want to convert a `Option(Tuple(N))` with n `T`s to a `List[T]`?

Comment: correct @saschakolberg that is what I'm asking, my use case is a bit more complicated as explained by the edit but thats a separate concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
val someOption: Option[(String, String)] = Some(("bla", "woo"))
val anotherOption: Option[String] = None

val someOptionList = for {
  (a, b) <- someOption.toList
  v <- List(a, b)
} yield v

val result = someOptionList ++ anotherOption.toList
```

or, to reduce constructions of intermediate collections:

```
val resultIter = someOption.iterator.flatMap {
  case (a, b) => Seq(a,b)
} ++ anotherOption.iterator

val result = resultIter.toList
```

Comment: Bit shorter last example `val result = someOption.toList.flatMap { case (a, b) => Seq(a,b) } ++ anotherOption`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well, the use case is still not absolutely clear to me.

However, here are some thoughts.

- The issue with your code is that, in a for comprehension, you always end up with the `Collection`(like) you start it, so in your case `Option`.
- There is always the possibility to just prepend another `Collection` to a list with `++:`.

So, maybe something like that?:

```
def addOptionTo(
  option: Option[(String, String)],
  list: List[SomeOtherThing]
): List[SomeOtherThing] = {
  option.map { case (foo, bar) => SomeOtherThing(foo, bar) } ++: list
}
```